# Dictionary Puzzle

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, correlation

Okay, so...
I have some dictionaries below that don't want to cooperate.
Dictionary "a" represents data stored in our HR database.
Dictionary "b" represents data stored in our AS400 iSeries data.
NOTE: THESE ARE NOT TRUE VALUES
The goal is to match a key in "a" to a key in "b" using at least 2 fields, while still being able to reference the key.

To put things another way, after I match 2 values, I want to be able to create a new dictionary that matches a's key to b's key:

```
match_dictionary[*key from a*] = (*key from b*)
a.pop(*key from a*)
b.pop(*key from b*)
```

Here's the code:

```
import collections
a = {'ada123456' : ('123','adam','jones') , 'jus567890':('567','justin','brady') , 'mul345678':('345','muller','thomas')}
b = {'ADAMJ' : ('123','jones') , 'JBRADY':('justin','brady') , 'THOMASM':('345','muller','thomas')}

if [i for i in [(x[1],x[2]) for x in [a[c] for c in a.keys()]]] in [b[d] for d in b.keys()]:
    print('Why won\'t this work?')

if ('justin','brady') in [b[d] for d in b.keys()]:
    print('\nthis works though')

if ('justin','brady') in [(x[1],x[2]) for x in [a[c] for c in a.keys()]]:
    print('\nthis too')
```

Comment: The new dictionary will have what values for those matched keys?

Comment: Would ('123', 'Brady', 'Thomas') match ('456', 'Thomas', 'Brady')?

Comment: The new dictionary would match key 'a' to key 'b' if they have 2 matching values.

Comment: And incorrect values don't matter? Like ('123', 'Sue', 'Brady')

Comment: @Steven Bell {'mul345678': 'THOMASM'} Is this your expected ans?

Comment: @Zev Not for the answer I want. I know how to filter out things that don't match. I'm looking for how to selectively choose values and then try to match them to another dictionaries values... then take the keys found to make that match and match the keys.

Comment: @VishalKhichadiya Yes

Comment: @Steven Bell look the solution !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it as key to a list in case you have more than one match

```
new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for b_name, b_values in b.items():
    for a_name, a_values in a.items():
        intersect = set(a_values).intersection(set(b_values))
        if len(intersect) >= 2:
            new_dict[a_name].append(b_name)
```

But it would be easy to change it to

```
            new_dict[a_name] = b_name
```

if you wanted. Then you wouldn't need the default dict.

This produces:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'ada123456': ['ADAMJ'],
             'jus567890': ['JBRADY'],
             'mul345678': ['THOMASM']})
```

if you want a normal `dict` back just wrap it in `dict()`